# OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow Problem - unsupported_grant_type

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I am trying to implement [OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm) and below is my code and debug log - any help is appreciated.

```
Http httpProtocol = new Http();   
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;');
request.setEndPoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
request.setMethod('POST');
String strbody = '{"grant_type":"Password", "password":"MY PASSWORD + TOKEN", "username":"SANDBOX USER NAME",  "client_secret":"secret",   "client_id":"Client id from remote setttings"}';
request.setBody(strbody);
HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
String jsonInput = response.getBody();
system.debug('jsonInput===>'+jsonInput);
```

Debug log -

```
15:55:38.068 (68324000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|System.HttpRequest.setMethod(String)
15:55:38.068 (68346000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[5]|System.HttpRequest.setMethod(String)
15:55:38.068 (68350000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[6]
15:55:38.068 (68356000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[6]|Bytes:357
15:55:38.068 (68381000)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[6]|strbody|"{\"grant_type\":\"Passw (337 more) ..."
15:55:38.068 (68387000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[7]
15:55:38.068 (68407000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[7]|System.HttpRequest.setBody(String)
15:55:38.068 (68440000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[7]|System.HttpRequest.setBody(String)
15:55:38.068 (68445000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[8]
15:55:38.068 (68478000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[8]|System.Http.send(APEX_OBJECT)
15:55:38.068 (68568000)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[8]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token, Method=POST]
15:55:38.483 (483258000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:219
15:55:38.483 (483399000)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[8]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
15:55:38.483 (483424000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:96
15:55:38.483 (483444000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[8]|System.Http.send(APEX_OBJECT)
15:55:38.483 (483615000)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[8]|response|"System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]"|0x1b22c3f1
15:55:38.483 (483627000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[9]
15:55:38.483 (483666000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[9]|System.HttpResponse.getBody()
15:55:38.483 (483742000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[9]|Bytes:81
15:55:38.483 (483751000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[9]|System.HttpResponse.getBody()
15:55:38.483 (483780000)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[9]|jsonInput|"{\"error\":\"unsupporte (61 more) ..."
15:55:38.483 (483786000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[10]
15:55:38.483 (483794000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:13
15:55:38.483 (483980000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:94
15:55:38.483 (483999000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[10]|System.debug(ANY)
15:55:38.484 (484025000)|USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|jsonInput===>{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class TestCallout {


     public static  void TestCallout(){


    String clientId = '3MVG982oBBDdwyHirurznY0bXVCZCrB6.9sxBfCGtr8ZKVUUzOPjhOcLypgBhgBugAN5XMKbPpNnQKwDCL8rk';
    String clientSecret = '9066826186886123605';
    String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&username='username'&password='password';

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(reqbody);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://data-na3--data.cs13.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');//Note if my domain is set up use the proper domain name else use login.salesforce.com for prod or developer or test.salesforce.com for sandbox instance

    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    system.debug('--------'+res.getBody());

    }

    }
```

Just was playing around and the above code works for me without any issue .Also agree with metadaddy that content-type in http  header can be set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded as best practice .

Comment: @PrafullaPatil If you are thinking of using this for integration i would say big no to this approach.This defeats process of authentication through oauth.You can ask the user to enter crendentials himself and then store oauth token somewhere in object and also there are ways of refreshing this token as well .Refer http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Comment: @metadaddy Thanks for this article http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com.This has helped lot in understanding oauth principles and also thanks for all your blog post on developer force .

Comment: is there any way I can do this without using username and password, with just clientSecret and clientId ? I will be using this for salesforce to salesforce integration.

Comment: At the first callout get the token and store in custom object and then only first time for a session you may need to make an oauth call and refresh the token if the token as expired .Read through the document  http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- The `content-type` HTTP header should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- The `grant_type` form parameter should be `password` (all lower case)