# HTTP POST Request from Salesforce Apex code to get access_token?

Tags: apex, callout, oauth2

I am new to `Salesforce` but aware about the `REST`. I'm trying to make the `HTTP POST` call to get the `access_token` first to call the actual `GET, PUT and POST` service.

I have written the following code in developer console and same will try in test class.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
request.setMethod('POST');

request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
request.setHeader('client_id','3MVG9d8..z.hDcPJZPIzGJ5UZDrL7bJthAQ_v0YCxzEeG1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
request.setHeader('client_secret','XXXXXXXXXXX');
request.setHeader('username','XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com');
request.setHeader('password','XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
request.setHeader('grant_type','password');

request.setBody('');

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
System.debug('Response :: '+response.getBody());
```

I am not sure when if we need to send above `data in header or body`? But when I tried using `header` I get the following error. Please guide further.

> Line: 15, Column: 1
>   System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

**When I tried in REST Client, it works fine.**

[image]

Comment: It's because you're making the callout *from* `Apex`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what you need to do. Before making any Http callout, you must first authorize the endpoint by adding it to your `Remote Site Settings`. Navigate to `Setup` > `Security` > `Remote Site Settings`, then add **`https://ap5.salesforce.com`**:

[image: New Remote Site]

See also: **[Adding Remote Site Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm)**:

> Before any Apex callout can call an external site, that site must be registered in the Remote Site Settings page, or the callout fails. Salesforce prevents calls to unauthorized network addresses.
>
> > Note
> >     If the callout specifies a named credential as the endpoint, you don’t need to configure remote site settings. A named credential specifies the URL of a callout endpoint and its required authentication parameters in one definition. To set up named credentials, see “Define a Named Credential” in the Salesforce Help.
>
> To add a remote site setting:
>
> 1. From Setup, enter Remote Site Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Remote Site Settings.
> 2. Click New Remote Site.
> 3. Enter a descriptive term for the Remote Site Name.
> 4. Enter the URL for the remote site.
> 5. Optionally, enter a description of the site.
> 6. Click Save.

Comment: Thank you. But now see the error: `20:31:55:021 USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|Response :: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}`

Comment: @user That's kind of a completely different question. You've now got the callout part working.

Comment: That said, if you sift through https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23239/rest-username-password-authentication-not-working...perhaps you need to specify a `callback_url` header.

Comment: Also take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5925/oauth-2-0-username-password-flow-problem-unsupported-grant-type, which indicates perhaps you should set your `content-type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Regardless, `unsupported_grant_type` is a completely separate error, and the fact you are getting that far means you have solved your initial issue. Better SFSE etiquette would be to post a separate question for it. If you keep changing your question as you encounter a new error, it makes your questions hard to answer.